# Angular ngIf two variables are the same (string and number)

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

So I have a variable `sight.pin_lang_id` that is loaded on the page. (Sometimes it is 1, sometimes 2).
I also have a service that gets `lang`. Currently it has a name and id. 
See picture below:

[image]

Now I want to display the `lang.name` only when the `lang.id` matches the `sight.pin_lang_id`.

I tried this with ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="sight.pin_lang_id == lang.id">
     {{lang.name}}
</div>
```

But I just get an error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'pin_lang_id' of undefined`

But when I do this, it works fine:

```
<div *ngIf="sight?.pin_lang_id == 2">
     show me
</div>
```

Note: `sight.pin_lang_id` is type of string, so in the console it shows "2". While `lang.id` is number 2, shows just 2.

How can I create a ngIf that checks if string is equal to number (from variables) ?

Comment: What exactly is now the problem, you compare a string with a number, which in your case seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish but you can either cast the number to a string or the string to a number

So something like

```
<div *ngIf="sight?.pin_lang_id == '2'">
     show me
</div>
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div *ngIf="sight?.pin_lang_id == lang.id">
     show me
</div>
```

That should be just fine, the issue is that when reading `sight` it may not have a value yet, so that's why the `?`

Answer (score -1):

The trick was to put the ngIf inside the ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let lang of langs" [lang]="lang">
    <div *ngIf="sight.pin_lang_id == lang.id">
        {{lang.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```